# Selenium Firefox Window Not Opening Until Idle Window Closes

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm relatively new to Selenium with Python - but have a script which works perfectly for me on a Mac. However, I'm trying to run it on a Windows 7 machine and am having some trouble I cannot explain. If I have the basic code:

```
br = webdriver.Firefox()

br.get('http://www.google.com')
```

To bring up a new webpage, this works fine on a Mac. However, when I run this through IDLE on my Win7 machine a Firefox window will not open. Not after ten seconds ore ten minutes. However, if I close out of the IDLE window the Firefox window finally opens. However this is too late as the program has been killed.

It's firefox 28.

Comment: What version of webdriver are you using?

Comment: Can you try running your script from command line, just to see what happens?